# XML support in Swagger (.Net Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Asp.net Core Swagger framework that we all use at work. It just wraps all the PITA stuff with Swagger. It was designed to be json in / json out. Now one group wants to use it with XML in / XML out only.

Here is what I've done so far:

1) Changed startup.cs to:

`services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

2) On controller methods, changed to:

```
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
```

3) In an operation filter, added:

```
operation.Produces.Add("application/xml");
```

Now, in the Test UI, I get only application/xml for the input & output drop downs. When I hit the test button, my request is getting deserialized properly, but the test page produces a 406 error.

What other things do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

The client needs to send an `Accepts` header which includes `application/xml`. You've set `application/xml` as the only possible response type, and if the client requests something like `application/json`, the server can no longer fulfill that request.

Comment: I meant test ui as in the built in swagger test page. That's where I'm seeing the 406 error. The request is coming in xml fine.

Comment: Yes, because the `Content-Type` header of the request is being sent as `application/xml`. However, that has *no* bearing on the `Accepts` header that is sent, and *that* is what determines the type the server responds with. If `application/xml` is not present in that header (which it obviously isn't) then the server cannot respond to the request as it can *only* return `application/xml` now. This is how content negotiation works.

Comment: Ok, I looked at what the swagger test page is sending and its sending: curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' --header 'Accept: application/xml' -d '<?xml version="1.0"?> \, so it has the Accept header already. It seems like the response is getting sent back in json still.

Comment: I tried in fiddler with both Accepts application/xml and Accepts application/json and neither work. Both get HTTP 406.